# os.path.isfile() return true only if the file is in directory

Tags: python

I try to use `os` to separate folder and file, but `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` returns `True` only if the file (or folder) is in the same folder than the program.

my code :

```
if(os.path.exists(".")):  # check if the folder exist    
    for x in os.listdir("."):                       
        if os.path.isfile(  os.path.abspath(x)): print('f',  x)
        elif os.path.isdir( os.path.abspath(x)): print('d',  x)
        elif os.path.islink(os.path.abspath(x)): print('l',  x)
        else:                                    print('n/a', x)
```

the console :

```
d left
f main.py
d right
```

my code to see inside of "left" folder:

```
if(os.path.exists(".\\left")):  # check if the folder exist           
    for x in os.listdir(".\\left"):                      
        if os.path.isfile(  os.path.abspath(x)): print('f',  x)
        elif os.path.isdir( os.path.abspath(x)): print('d',  x)
        elif os.path.islink(os.path.abspath(x)): print('l',  x)
        else:                                    print('n/a', x)
```

the console :

```
n/a normalFile.txt
n/a normalFolder
```

I really don't understand why `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isdir()` return `False`.

Comment: Because you're not telling the `os` functions that your file is anywhere other than the current directory. Use `os.path.join(folder, x)` instead of just `x`

Comment: The variable `x` contains only the filename. You are checking if the file exists in the current directory. You must use `os.path.join` to join paths.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`os.listdir()` just returns filenames. You need to join them with the directory name to get the full path.

```
if(os.path.exists(".\\left")):  # check if the folder exist           
    for x in os.listdir(".\\left"):
        fullpath = os.path.join( ".\\left", x)                  
        if os.path.isfile(  fullpath): print('f',  x)
        elif os.path.isdir( fullpath): print('d',  x)
        elif os.path.islink(fullpath): print('l',  x)
        else:                          print('n/a', x)
```

`os.path.abspath()` can't do that by itself because it doesn't know what directory `x` came from.

Comment: As a side note, using `".\\"` may cause cross-platform issues (and simply using `"left"` should work anyway).

Comment: @Selcuk A raw string or forward slash is usually the simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

It will be far better for you getting used to working with [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#module-pathlib) when dealing with paths. Look how simple it is:

```py
from pathlib import Path

path = Path(".\\left")
if path.exists():  # check if the folder exist           
    for x in path.iterdir():                      
        if x.is_file():      print('f',  x)
        elif x.is_dir():     print('d',  x)
        elif x.is_symlink(): print('l',  x)
        else:                print('n/a', x)
```